# ValueError at / (Required parameter name not set)

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

I am trying to make a blog app using django and python. I am also trying to use s3 buckets for storage and heroku for deployment.I am follow a tutorial online by coreymschafer. I am doing everything exactly as the tutorial, yet i am getting that error. I have no idea what to do. Please help!

I have also installed boto3 and django-storages. However, I feel that the problem is with boto3 for some reason[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xebbF.png). i have attached a screenshot of the problem,also just wanted to state that there is no problem with base.html

PLEASE HELP! THANK YOU

I added these to my settings.py file:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')

AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

Comment: can you make sure if you have set the environment variables properly in heroku?

Comment: Yeah, I have. I have been researching on this issue for an hour, I still don't know what the problem is

Answer (score 11):

Had the same issue.
Commented out this line and the code was working fine again:

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

Found out it was because, even if i had already restarted my PC, one of Environmental variable I was referencing was improperly set:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
```

I checked using Python console using:

```
import os
print(os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'))
print(os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'))
print(os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME'))
```

and made sure that Python can access all the values properly.
Then brought back the :

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

Comment: I had a spelling mistake, a "double underscore"at one variabe,  propably from copy pasting .... Thanks, this helped me find it.

Comment: I forgot to add an environment variable to my config. So stupid, in a hurry, thanks for opening my eyes!

Answer (score 2):

kill the your local server, close your command prompt. And restart your command prompt.
Run the server again and try.
If after doing that your have this error : The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
Put this in your settings.py :

```
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'us-east-2' #change to your region
AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = 's3v4'
```

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that the server didn't update it's environment variables.
Try hard restarting your server for environment variables to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as yours and probably you did not set the AWS environment variables in the server-side although you set them in your local machine. So, you can copy the export commands in your local .bash_profile file where you set AWS environment variables and paste them into the .bash_profile file in the server-side.

Answer (score 0):

I also followed the same tutorial.
I faced exactly same issue when I deployed it on heroku.

It got resolved when I added the environment variables to heroku using

**heroku config:set variable_name="value"**

Hopefully this resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you followed all the advice on comments and still does not work, add the following code in the `settings.py`:

```
AWS_S3_ADDRESSING_STYLE = 'virtual'
```

This worked for me, and I'm in `us-east-2` region. If your region is different, consider reading this issue on [Github](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/issues/782). (found my solution there, after I followed all the advice below.)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone was following the tutorial and stumbled on this question, if you are using MacOS Catalina or beyond, the terminal has changed from bash to zsh.

I added my environment variables in .zshenv and was able to solve this issue.

Answer (score -1):

comment down the line

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

I did have the same issue.
Tha way I solved it was this:

1. Go to your AWS console
2. Choose the name of your bucket
3. Choose properties
4. Choose Encryption
5. Click on Read more.. (this will lead you to your permissions tab)
6. Unblock permissions.

I know this isn't the best way and practices to do it. But I could move along.
If anyone here has the same trouble, please share!